# Seo benefit of multi store using subdirectories

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

Instead of using multi store for multiple languages, my thought is to use it for SEO. create multiple stores using sub-directories... i.e. [site].com/uk/ and then using the webmaster tools geotargeting tool accordingly. Any thoughts about how this would, or would not, work?